# Issues using the voice guide

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I am trying to make my bot leave the voice channel, using the code from [discordjs guide](https://discordjs.guide/voice/voice-connections.html#access) (discord version dev 14.0.0 )

when I try to acces the created connection, it errors: `ReferenceError: myVoiceChannel is not defined`.

my code in the leave command:

```js
const Command = require('../Structures/Command.js');
const { getVoiceConnection } = require("@discordjs/voice");
const connection = getVoiceConnection(myVoiceChannel.guild.id);



module.exports = new Command({
    name: "lvc",
    description: "leaves voice",
    permission: "CONNECT",

    async run(message, args, client) {
        connection.destroy();        
    }
})
```

my code in the join command:

```js
const Command = require('../Structures/Command.js');
const { VoiceConnectionStatus, AudioPlayerStatus, AudioPlayer, joinVoiceChannel } = require('@discordjs/voice');


module.exports = new Command({
    name: "join",
    description: "joins voice",
    permission: "CONNECT",

    async run(message, args, client) {
        const connection = joinVoiceChannel({
            channelId: "904277856773869583",
            guildId: message.guild.id,
            adapterCreator: message.guild.voiceAdapterCreator
        })
    }, 

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first code you've added the code

```js
const connection = getVoiceConnection(myVoiceChannel.guild.id);
```

Nowhere in your code you've defined `myVoiceChannel`. This is the reason why this error is being thrown. You could use this example instead:

```js
const Command = require('../Structures/Command.js');
const { getVoiceConnection } = require("@discordjs/voice");


module.exports = new Command({
    name: "lvc",
    description: "leaves voice",
    permission: "CONNECT",

    async run(message, args, client) {
        const connection = getVoiceConnection(message.guild.id);
        if(connection) connection.destroy();
        else return message.channel.send({ content: `I am not connected to a voice channel` });
    }
})
```